# On the proof that $1_{\textbf{Set}}$ is representable

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, functors, representable-functor

[Example 4.1.4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) says:

> Consider $H^1:\textbf{Set}\to\textbf{Set}$, there $1$ is the one-element set. Since a map from $1$ to a set $B$ amounts to an element of $B$, we have $$H^1(B)\cong B$$ for each set $B$. It is easily verified that this isomorphism is natural in $B$, so $H^1$ is isomorphic to the identity functor $1_{\textbf{Set}}$.

In my understanding, the isomorphism mentioned at the end is constructed as follows. Let $\eta$ be the natural transformation from $H^1$ to $1_{\textbf{Set}}$ defined by $\eta_A(\star\mapsto a)= a$. That is, $\eta_A:H^1(A)\to 1_{\textbf{Set}}(A)$ is the arrow (in the category of sets) that sends the map $\star\mapsto a$ to $a$ (where $Ob(1)=\{\star\})$. If $f:A\to B$ is an arrow in the category of sets, one sees that the diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^1(A) @>{H^1(f)}>> H^1(B);\\
@VVV @VVV \\
1_{\textbf{Set}}(A)=A @>{1_{\textbf{Set}}(f)=f}>> 1_{\textbf{Set}}(B)=B;
\end{CD}$$

commutes. Now one can similarly define the natural transformation $\epsilon$ from $1_{\textbf{Set}}$ to $H^1$ by $\epsilon_A(a)=(\star\mapsto a)$ and prove that both vertical compositions of $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ are identity transformations.

Now for my questions:

0) Is my proof correct?

1) I haven't used that $H^1(B)\cong B$ at all. Why does the text refer to this isomorphism? Is there another way to prove the desired claim using this fact?

<s>2) I don't remember the notion of an isomorphism being "natural in" $B$ defined before, and there are no results (when using ctrl+F in the cited document) for "natural in" that appear before this example. What's the precise definition of this notion?</s> I think Definition 1.3.12 is used here. See [On the definition of $F(A)$ being isomorphic to $G(A)$ naturally in $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278314/on-the-definition-of-fa-being-isomorphic-to-ga-naturally-in-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is indeed correct. As for the second question: note that a natural transformation $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism if and only if every component is an isomorphism in the target category of $F$ and $G$. Thus, instead of describing an explicit inverse for $\eta$, you could have just observed that the arrow

$$
\eta_B : f \in \mathsf{Set}(1,B) \mapsto f(\ast) \in B
$$

is an isomorphism for any set $B$. This is what the author is referring to, and what you are indirectly proving.

**Edit:** for completeness sake and to clear some doubts, I'll include the following result,

> ***Proposition.*** Let $F,G : C \to D$ be two functors and $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$  a natural transformation. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism.
> - $\alpha_c : Fc \to Gc$ is an isomorphism for all $c \in \mathsf{ob}(C)$.

*Proof.* Suppose that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, so that there exists $\beta : G \Rightarrow F$ with $\alpha \beta = 1_G$ and $\beta \alpha = 1_F$. Then, for each object $c \in \mathsf{ob}(C)$ we have

$$
\alpha_c\beta_c = (\alpha\beta)_c = (1_F)_c = 1_{Gc}
$$

and similarly $\beta_c\alpha_c = 1_{Fc}$. Hence $\alpha_c$ is an isomorphism with inverse $\beta_c$.

Reciprocally, suppose that $\alpha_c$ is an isomorphism for each $c \in \mathsf{ob}(C)$, and note $\beta_c$ the inverse of $\alpha_c$.

If $f : x \to y$ is an arrow in $C$, by naturality of $\alpha_c$ we obtain

$$
\alpha_{y}Ff = Gf \alpha_x.
$$

Right-composing by $\beta_y$ yields $Ff = \beta_y Gf\alpha_x$ and left-composing by $\beta_x$ we conclude that

$$
Ff\beta_x = \beta_yGf.
$$

This is to say that the collection of arrows $(\beta_c : Gc \to Fc)_{c \in \mathsf{ob}(C)}$ assembles into a natural transformation. Since by hypothesis each $\beta_c$ is the inverse of $\alpha_c$, it follows that $\beta \alpha = 1_F$ and $\alpha \beta  = 1_G$. Therefore $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism.$\ \square$

Comment: Indeed, this is Lemma 1.3.11. But then why do we need to check that $H^1(B)\cong B$ *naturally in* $B$? The lemma says that $\alpha:F\implies G$ is a natural isomorphism iff $\alpha_A$ is an isomorphism for all $A$. It doesn't say anything about whether $F(A)\cong G(A)$ is natural in $A$ or not.

Comment: Indeed so, as the author says one should check that these isomorphisms are natural. But this is what you have done when defining $\eta$. To be concrete: once you know that a family of isomorphisms are the components of a natural transformation, they form a natural isomorphism.

Comment: To clear something up, the terminology 'the maps $\nu_c : Fc \to Gc$ are natural in $c$' means that $\nu : F \Rightarrow G$ is a natural transformation. So when the author says that $\mathsf{Set}(1,B) \simeq B$ naturally in $B$, this amounts to having a family of isomorphisms $\mathsf{Set}(1,B) \to B$ that form a natural transformation, i.e., a natural isomorphism.

Comment: Okay, so if we don't know that $H^1(B)\cong B$ is natural in $B$, then we don't know whether the family of arrows $(H^1(B)\to B)_{B\in\mathscr A}$ are the components of a natural transformation or not. But then it seems the fact that $H^1(B)\to B$ is an isomorphism is not significant in verifying that $(H^1(B)\to B)_{B\in\mathscr A}$ is a natural transformation. This raises the question: if $F,G:\mathscr A\to \mathscr B$ are functors and $F(A)\to G(A)$ is an arrow, can one define the notion of this arrow $F(A)\to G(A)$ being natural in $A$ (by saying that $(F(A)\to G(A))_{A\in\mathscr A}$ ...

Comment: ...forms a natural transformation)? I.e., we don't need that the arrow $F(A)\to G(A)$ be an isomorphism to define naturality in $A$, do we? Edit: oh I see that you defined naturality in $c$ for an arbitrary arrow, so you already answered my question. I was confused by the fact that Leinster defines naturality only for isomorphisms.

Comment: @user634426 yeah, this can be said of any collection of arrows. It's just another notation for the same thing. As you can see in the other post, this can be useful when dealing with functors with multiple inputs.

Comment: I hope this will be my last comment. To make things more precise, I think what is used here is not Lemma 1.3.11 but the following statement. $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism between $F$ and $G$ iff (1) $\alpha_A: F(A)\to G(A)$ is natural in $A$, and (2) $\alpha_A: F(A)\to G(A)$ is an isomorphism. Is it true? The forward implication is obvious, but for the backward implication I couldn't show that conditions (1), (2) imply that $\alpha_A^{-1}:G(A)\to F(A)$ is natural in $A$ (which is I believe what is needed to prove my claim). If the claim is true, I'll keep trying or ask a separate question.

Comment: The statement $(1)$ makes no sense, as $\alpha$ is already a natural transformation. One usually says that an arrow is natural with respect to some object if changing the objects we obtain a family of arrows which is a natural transformation. For completeness, I'll add a proof of the original claim.

Comment: A priori $\alpha$ is just a family of arrows $(\alpha_A)_{A\in\mathscr A}$. I posted a separate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279085/a-claim-about-a-family-of-arrows-forming-a-natural-isomorphism